# output comes out with brackets and quotation marks

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to print this function but the output comes out with brackets and quotation marks... like this

> ('1', ',December', ',1984')

```
def date_string(day_num, month_name, year_num):
    """ Turn the date into a string of the form
            day month, year
    """
    date = str(day_num) , "," + month_name , "," + str(year_num)
    return date
print(date_string(1, "December", 1984))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date = str(day_num) , "," + month_name , "," + str(year_num)
```

With this code, you're creating a tuple and not a string.

To create a string instead, you have multiple options:

```
date = '{} {},{}'.format(day_num, month_name, year_num) # Recommended method
```

OR

```
date = '%s %s, %s' % (day_num, month_name, year_num) # Fairly outdated
```

OR use `+` for concatenation, as per the other answers. Using `+` for string concatenation is not ideal, as you must make sure you convert each operand to a string type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have some commas `,` where you need plus signs `+`:

```
    date = str(day_num) , "," + month_name , "," + str(year_num)
```

This is creating a tuple instead of a string.  Change it to:

```
    date = str(day_num) + "," + month_name + "," + str(year_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `,` to a `+` when creating the variable `date`. This creates a string rather than a list.

```
def date_string(day_num, month_name, year_num):
""" 
        Turn the date into a string of the form
        day month, year
"""
date = str(day_num) + ", " + month_name + ", " + str(year_num)
return date
print(date_string(1, "December", 1984))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python version `3.6` or newer, you might use so-called f-strings for that task, following way

```
def date_string(day_num, month_name, year_num):
    date = f"{day_num},{month_name},{year_num}"
    return date
print(date_string(1, "December", 1984)) #output: 1,December,1984
```

Keep in mind that it doesn't work with older versions of Python, so please check your version before using it. If you want to know more about f-strings read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).